# imagick and mongo on OSX lion with brew

Tags: mongodb, osx-lion, homebrew, imagick

I am trying to install imagick and mongo on osx lion. Note that my php installation is done via homebrew. I have installed the packages correctly and it should work but php returns the following

Warning: PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Any clues on how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP errors indicate that you've compiled extensions for a different API version (*20090626* API is PHP 5.3) from the server you are trying to use the extensions with (*20100525* API is PHP 5.4).

I suspect that you have installed PHP 5.4 via homebrew, but managed to pick up the OS X default headers (PHP 5.3) when compiling the extensions.  You need to either recompile your extensions with PHP 5.4, or downgrade your web server to PHP 5.3.

You can check the version of PHP headers in your path using `php-config`:

```
php-config --version
```

And the version of PHP and extension API with:

```
php -i | egrep "PHP (Extension|Version)"
```

Possible fixes:

1. Include `/usr/local/bin` in your path first so the homebrew PHP versions are found in preference to the system default:

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
   ```
2. Install PHP 5.3 via Homebrew:

   ```
   brew uninstall php54

   brew install php53
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I'd like to add that
when brew installs php it sets the additional ini files read folder to
/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php5/conf.d

whilst it actually is
/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d

you can easily fix that by symlinking

```
cd /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/
mkdir php5
cd php5
ln -s ../conf.d .
```